# Using a Javascript Variable & Sending to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, hash, object

I'm trying to take a URL's hash value, send it through a function, turn that value into an object, but ultimately send the value to JSON. I have the following setup:

```
function content(cur){
    var mycur = $H(cur);
    var pars = "p="+mycur.toJSON();
    new Ajax.Updater('my_box', 'test.php', {
      parameters: pars
    });
}   

function update(){
    if(window.location.hash.length > 0){
        content(window.location.hash.substr(1)); // Everything after the '#'
    }   
}

var curHashVal = window.location.hash;
window.onload = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        if(curHashVal != window.location.hash){
            update();
            curHashVal = window.location.hash;
        }
        },1);
    }
```

But for some reason, I can't seem to get the right JSON output. It will either return as a very large object (1:"{",2:"k") or not return at all. I doubt that it is impossible to accomplish, but I've exhausted most of the ways I can think of.

Other ways I've tried were "{" + cur + "}" as well as cur.toObject(), however, none seemed to get the job done.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: As an end result, I'd like the URL (say product:3,confirmed:1) to be returned as `{"product":3,"confirmed":1}`

Comment: Why not build up the json manually.

Comment: What library/framework is this written for?

Comment: @James Black: I'm trying to make the script as flexible as possible, so there are no real values that we know pre-defined. 

@harto: Prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for my answer, here's the solution!

```
function build_json(str){
    var new_str = "{";
    var cut = str.split(",");
    for(var x=0; x < cut.length; x++){
        if(x > 0){new_str = new_str+",";}
        var s = cut[x].split(":");
        new_str = new_str+"\""+s[0]+"\":\""+s[1]+"\"";
    }
    return new_str+"}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A typical implementation of toJSON() needs either an Array or an Object as the top-most element. Sonsomethig like this will probably work:

var pars = {p: myCur};
pars = pars.toJSON();

Answer (score 0):

First of all native JSON support and the `toJSON`method is not available in all browsers. Older browsers like IE 6/7 or Firefox 2/3 do not support it. You should use a JSON library like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) by Douglas Crockford. Second I would suggest to use the `stringify` method of the global `JSON` object instead of the `toJSON` function. In my tests

```
JSON.stringify("...")
```

works just fine.